# Run function depending on focus using "vue shortkey"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use the "Vue shortkey" library since the scope of the shortcuts is global but a detail arises

I am trying to execute two different functions using the same keyCode depending on their focus or their position.

and I need them to be executed according to the order, first the child and then the father

I have this:

```
<div v-shortkey="['esc']" @shortkey="closeModal">
    ...
    <div v-shortkey="['esc']" @shortkey="closeMenu">
         ...
     </div>
</div>
```

what I get is that the child is always executed leaving the parent aside.

Is there a way to execute the functions using the same keyCode?

Comment: not familiar with the library, but why not give the child a function that can do both:  `closeAll() { closeMenu(); closeModal(); }` and on the child div: `@shortkey="closeAll"`